# Need help in Image.save()

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am working on save a .tiff file from an array the code is :

```
image_array = np.vstack(band1,band2,band3)
image=Image.fromarray(image_array,mode='RGB')
file_name='img2.tiff'
image.save(file_name,format='TIFF')
```

But it is giving me error:

```
***error: argument out of range ***
```

As I am working on a very large file and large dataset. I am facing problem for the 2nd image but the 1st image is also very big but a little bit small in shape. What should I do

I was expecting the code to run and save the file using this fnx. from PIL library, so that I can pre-process the data

Comment: Try `print(image_array.dtype, image_array.shape)`

Comment: my array is of uint8 as i code I specified the value when converting to numpy array and the shape of the array is (32797,44161,3) it worked earlier when the array was of (31637,42835,3)

Comment: Which line gives the error? You may need `Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None` near the top.

Comment: `(32797,44161,3)` is larger than 4 GB and exceeds the size of classic TIFF files. Try to use compression to reduce the file size or use a library that can write BigTIFF format (e.g. [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/))

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Than you for your feed back. It is giving me error when i run the last line to save the image. I also used 'Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS=None' But it gave me same error.

Comment: Hi @cgohlke, I want to ask that if i use tifffile library it would not make any changes to the array I am saving with the same method as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cgohlke points out in the comments, your file exceeds 4GB if uncompressed. As such, that would require a BigTIFF which PIL cannot write. You can see this with:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Synthesize image data same size as yours
d = np.zeros((32797,44161,3), np.uint8)

# Check size
print(d.size)                 # prints 4,345,044,951 - too big for regular TIFF

# Make into PIL Image
im = Image.fromarray(d)

# Try to save
im.save("result.tif")         # ERROR 'L' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295

# Try to save compressed - WORKS
im.save("result.tif", compression='tiff_lzw')
```

So, it is rather unsatisfactory that you are reliant on compression to be able to save your image - though it may work. I think you would be well advised to take Christoph's advice and use [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) or another library - such as `wand`.

If your data is satellite imagery, there are often large areas of black where the swathes are offset as a result of Earth's rotation, these should be readily compressible so that may work in your favour.

---

I note that **OpenCV** can save your file and it too uses lossless LZW compression.

```
import cv2

# Write Numpy array 'd' from above as TIFF
cv2.imwrite('result.tif', d)
```

However, it too fails if you give it less compressible data:

```
# Make less compressible data
d = np.random.randint(0, 256, (32797,44161,3), np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite('result.tif', d)     # !!! FAILS !!!
```

Comment: Thank you yeah my data is satellite imargery for landset it worked using BigTiff file but also worled with imsave